Adding a roving watermark in Premiere?
I want to add a watermark that follows a defined path around the screen throughout the whole video, kind of like the logo in this video youtube.com/watch?v=QOtuX0jL85Y (although that path is random).
The goal is so it cannot easily be blurred.
Is there a free plugin or technique that lets you set a path for the watermark to follow?
Using Premiere 2022 fyi.
Thanks!

I suggest you don't really need a plugin to do this:

Add your logo to a sequence
Move it to the first position where you want it to appear
Add a position keyframe
Continue through the sequence, moving the image to different positions on screen
After a minute or so, copy the first position keyframe to the end of your one minute sequence.
Nest your sequence
Copy the nested sequence
Go to the beginning of your nested sequence, and paste repeatedly until your sequence fills the duration you need.

You could then nest this sequence, to make it easier to manage as a single block.
Move it to a track above your footage.
Adjust opacity and/or blend mode to taste.
